# Issue populating UITableViewCells with 'values' from dictionary

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, nsdictionary

I have an iOS app which is making a GET request to my API to get all the posts, which are saved to a database.

I am trying to populate the data retrieved into UITableView cells. Here is the main code used:

```
  if let jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: 
  data, options : .allowFragments) as? [Dictionary<String,Any>]
   {
                   print(jsonArray) // use the json here

                    //loop through the jsonArray (which holds the objects)
                    for deal in jsonArray {

                        //loop through indivdual objects
                        for (key, value) in deal {

                            var newDeal:Deal!

                            print(key, value)
                            if(key == "location"){
                                newDeal.address = value as! String //after assigning, newDeal is null
                            }
                            if(key == "description"){
                                newDeal.description = value as! String //after assigning, newDeal is null
                            }
                            if(key == "promotion_end"){
                                newDeal.availability = value as! String //after assigning, newDeal is null
                            }
                            if(key == "user_id"){
                                newDeal.poster = value as! String //after assigning, newDeal is null
                            }
                            if(key == "created_at"){
                                newDeal.postedOn = value as! String //after assigning, newDeal is null
                            }
                            self.deals.append(newDeal)//null error
                        }

                        //Example of Deal object:
                        //    Deal(poster: "Company name", postedOn: "2020-02-15", description: "Body of post goes here", availability: "11am-2pm Sat/Sun", address: "300 Somewhere Street")
                    }
```

I'm looping through each object within the jsonArray. I am checking the name of the key, and if the key is for example == to 'location', then setting the value associated with the key to the address, in an attempt to 'build up' the Deal object for each tableView cell as the for loop executes.

Why are the newDeal.address, newDeal.description etc. null after assigning the value? Please see below for several images that I captured while debugging, for the format of the data.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is supposed to crash because you are declaring `newDeal` as implicit unwrapped optional but you don't initialize it.

The loop can be simplified, you have to create an instance of `Deal`

```
for deal in jsonArray {
    let newDeal = Deal(poster: deal["user_id"] as! String,
                       postedOn: deal["created_at"] as! String,
                       description: deal["description"] as! String,
                       availability: deal["promotion_end"] as! String,
                       address: deal["location"] as! String)
    self.deals.append(newDeal)
}
```

I recommend to decode the JSON with `JSONDecoder` which is more comfortable.